# To make Sqlite3 table name as Python list?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I Want to make the table name as python list.

I tried to it. but I saw table name was just i(FOR statement variable) and python said 'table i already exists'.

I don't know wrong sector. please answer this problem.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\Kun\\Documents\\Dashin\\stock.db")
cursor = con.cursor()

stock_name = ['google','apple','amazon']

for i in stock_name:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE i(Code text)")
    con.commit()

con.close()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kun\Documents\Dashin\code.py", line 35, in <module>
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE i(Code text)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: table i already exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE i(Code text)")
```

You don't use the value inside `i`. Change it with this:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE %s(Code text)" % (i))
```

Furthermore the execution of your code creates durable tables, so, if you run this code more than one time, you will get the same `Table already exists` error.

Comment: Thanks. I can handle this way. Have a nice day!